# Excel - How to disable the macro of the inactive sheet

Tags: excel, vba

I have two Excel files that I usually keep open at the same time : one has a macro and the other one no. Problem is that when both of them are opened the macro works also on the file that does not have it and it's a problem. How do I make sure that it will only work on the file where it was created ?

OS : WIN Vista Business 16

Macro :

```
Sub riordino()
'
' riordino Macro
' Macro recorded 4/14/2007 by User
'
' Keyboard Shortcut: Ctrl+l
'
    Range("A1:L200").Select
    Selection.Sort Key1:=Range("C2"), Order1:=xlAscending, Key2:=Range("D2") _
        , Order2:=xlAscending, Key3:=Range("A2"), Order3:=xlAscending, Header:= _
        xlGuess, OrderCustom:=1, MatchCase:=False, Orientation:=xlTopToBottom
    Range("A2").Select
    ActiveWorkbook.Save
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

A first approach is this, but it will only work for a single named sheet. If you wanto to use it in many sheets, just tell.

```
Sub riordino() ' ' riordino Macro ' Macro recorded 4/14/2007 by User ' ' Keyboard Shortcut: Ctrl+l ' 
    Dim MyBook as WorkBook
    Dim MySheet as Worksheet
    Set MyBook = Application.Workbooks("YourWorkBookName") 'filename
    Set MySheet = MyBook.Worksheets("WorksheetName")

    MySheet.Range("A1:L200").Sort Key1:=Range("C2"), Order1:=xlAscending, Key2:=Range("D2"), Order2:=xlAscending, Key3:=Range("A2"), Order3:=xlAscending, Header:=xlGuess, OrderCustom:=1, MatchCase:=False, Orientation:=xlTopToBottom 
    MySheet.Range("A2").Select 
    MyBook.Save 
End Sub
```

---

Another approach, that works with the active sheet (the one you see in the screen only). In this case, the file is not saved,

```
Sub riordino() ' ' riordino Macro ' Macro recorded 4/14/2007 by User ' ' Keyboard Shortcut: Ctrl+l ' 
    Dim MySheet as Worksheet
    Set MySheet = Application.ActiveSheet
    MySheet.Range("A1:L200").Sort Key1:=Range("C2"), Order1:=xlAscending, Key2:=Range("D2"), Order2:=xlAscending, Key3:=Range("A2"), Order3:=xlAscending, Header:=xlGuess, OrderCustom:=1, MatchCase:=False, Orientation:=xlTopToBottom 
    MySheet.Range("A2").Select 
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

this will help test if the macro should activate - check `ThisWorkbook` against `ActiveWorkbook`

Example:

```
Public Sub test1()
If ThisWorkbook.Name = ActiveWorkbook.Name Then
    Debug.Print "ok to run"
Else
    Debug.Print "not ok"
End If
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

You could place your macro code inside the worksheet module for the sheet it runs on.
Doing this gives you access to the `Me` object, with in this case would refer to the worksheet. So you dont need to hard-code the sheet name, and while you can call the sub from elsewhere it will exit out before any changes are made.

eg: If your macro runs on sheet1, you would place it inside the sheet1 module.

```
Sub riordino()

If Not Me.Name = Application.ActiveSheet.Name Then Exit Sub

Me.Range("A1:L22").Sort _
    Key1:=Me.Range("C2"), _
    Order1:=xlAscending, _
    Key2:=Me.Range("D2"), _
    Order2:=xlAscending, _
    Key3:=Me.Range("A2"), _
    Order3:=xlAscending, _
    Header:=xlGuess, _
    OrderCustom:=1, _
    MatchCase:=False, _
    Orientation:=xlSortRows

Me.Range("A2").Select

ThisWorkbook.Save

End Sub
```

**Update**

When you use the macro recorder to create a macro it will create a module, called "Module 1" (or 2 or 3 etc). If you open the VBA Editor, and look in the project explorer, there will be an item called "Sheet 1" (or in your case "Current"). Double click that item and paste the code in the editor window.

[image: image showing the worksheet module in the vba project explorer]

**Update 2**

When you're posting code please edit *your* question and include it there, it makes it easier to read and everyone can read it without trauling through comments.

You need to modify the generated code to be similar to mine. The differences are minimal so if you have any other similar macros it should be fairly simple to adjust the rest. (the formatting of the code does not matter, its just for readability)

```
Sub Ordinare()
If Not Me.Name = Application.ActiveSheet.Name Then Exit Sub
Me.Range("A2:L201").Sort _
    Key1:=Me.Range("C2"), _
    Order1:=xlAscending, _
    Key2:=Me.Range("D2"), _
    Order2:=xlAscending, _
    Key3:=Me.Range("A2"), _
    Order3:=xlAscending, _
    Header:= xlGuess, _
    OrderCustom:=1, _
    MatchCase:=False, _
    Orientation:=xlTopToBottom, _
    DataOption1:=xlSortNormal, _
    DataOption2:=xlSortNormal, _
    DataOption3:= xlSortNormal
Me.Range("A2").Select
ThisWorkbook.Save
End Sub
```

Once you paste this into the "Sheet N(Current)" module the "Module11" is no longer required. (keeping it will cause problems) The keyboard shortcut will also no longer function either, you will have to re-configure it using the "edit" button in the macros dialog in the main excel window.

Comment: Thanks Nick and all for your replies. I am not sure on how to place the macro inside the worksheet module. The sheet name I am using the macro for is called "Current"

Comment: Thank you very much for your help. This is the code of the macro I have created :Sub Ordinare()
'
' Ordinare Macro
' Macro recorded 30-05-2013 by Pakal
'
' Keyboard Shortcut: Ctrl+p
'
    Range("A2:L201").Select
    Selection.Sort Key1:=Range("C2"), Order1:=xlAscending, Key2:=Range("D2") _
        , Order2:=xlAscending, Key3:=Range("A2"), Order3:=xlAscending, Header:= _
        xlGuess, OrderCustom:=1, MatchCase:=False, Orientation:=xlTopToBottom, _
        DataOption1:=xlSortNormal, DataOption2:=xlSortNormal, DataOption3:= _
        xlSortNormal
    ActiveWorkbook.Save
End Sub

Comment: What you are saying is that I should copy this code into the editor window of the Sheet2(Current). Should I still leave Module 11 there or should it be deleted ? Can you please edit the code of this macro so that it will work when pasted into the Sheet2(Current) . Thanks a million.